# how to add new element and post its values in php using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to add a new element every button click and i want to post their values in php... 
so far ive started coding but i think im lost..

here is my jquery that adds new element

```
//this is the button that adds new element 
$('#addnew').click(function(){
$("<input type='text' class='in'/><br>").appendTo('#d');
});
```

and here is my method to post the value

```
$('#save').click(function(){
$('#resultdiv').load('myphp.php',{Values: <!--i dont know what to pass here--> });
});
```

and here is my php

```
<? echo"$_POST[Values]";?>
```

this portion is where the elements are added

```
<div id='d'>
<!--ADDED ELEMENTS WILL GOES HERE-->

<input type='button' id='addnew' value'ADD NEW'>
<input type='button' id='save' value='save'>
</div>
```

and here is the div for the reult

```
<div id='resultdiv'>
</div>
```

please help me how to figure this out..thanks

Comment: this was solve by 3nigma

Comment: $('document').ready(function(){ 
     $('#save').click(function(e){ 
     var ser = $(".do").serialize(); 
      e.preventDefault(); 
     $('#res').load('do.php',{Values:$.makeArray(ser) }); 

     }); 


     }); 

     </script></head>
    <body>
    <input type='text' class='do' name="do"><br> 
     <input type='text' class='do' name="do"><br> 
     <input type='text' class='do' name="do"><br> 
    <input type='button' id='save' value='go2'><br>


    <div id='res'></div>

Answer (score 1):

Put inside the click this statement which will update the value of the input type via "ID"

```
i=0
$('#ElementName'+i).value(Value_Variable);
i++;
```

Let me know if there is a problem

--updated the answer

Comment: no it will be incremental with $i in php and +i in jquery/javascript. You will have to call the attr("id") from the .class

Answer (score 0):

serialize the values using `serialize` and then convert them to array using `makeArray`

```
var ser = $(".in").serialize();
$('#save').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$('#resultdiv').load('myphp.php',{Values: $.makeArray(ser) });

 });
```

dont know much about the php stuff but you can try the following code

```
foreach ($_POST['Values'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: thanks 3nigma for that reply.... but how could i echo the 'Values' in php...thanks

Comment: i tried your code but it seems not working...it doesnt print anything

Comment: try `print_r($_POST['Values'])` see  what it prints also there was a typo in the answer `$_POST['Values']`

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\beta\jquery\forms\do.php on line 5

Comment: i got that error...i think it does not pass any values at all

Comment: so its the syntax error in the foreach, try `$var = $_POST['Values']; print_r($var);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7935/discussion-between-3nigma-and-nj-lac)